# What's the name for this piece attached to the kitchen faucet hose?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-sink

Some time ago, I had a lot of rust and debris come into our plumbing due to some maintenance work my city did. Since then, my kitchen faucet cold water has been coming in pretty slowly. When I finally decided to do something about it tonight, I accidentally snapped off some tabs on this piece:

[image: profile]

This was quick-connected on one side to the copper after hot and cold water join (and where the tabs snapped off):

[image: quick connect side]

The other side is threaded and screwed into the braided nylon hose that goes back up to the faucet:

[image: threaded side]

Unfortunately, I have no idea what this piece is called, there's no brand name to be found on this or on the rest of the faucet, and looking at replacement faucet assemblies gives me no clue as to what this is. I'd like to replace just this piece if possible.

The inside of this looks quite rusty. I got the impression that it's some sort of a debris filter, but I don't know that it's actually the case. While I'm not sure what purpose this serves, I am now able to attach everything together, holding this piece firmly but manually in-place, and water comes out fantastic. But if this thing slides off, turning on the faucet will spill water everywhere since there are no longer tabs to keep it in.

*Edit*: Added picture of this piece as installed. Arrows show the direction of flow of water. Blue and red are cold and hot water coming in from the wall and up into the faucet assembly; purple is after these two join together and go back down, through the piece in question; yellow is through the nylon hose, which goes down and back up into the faucet head.

[image: piece installed]

Comment: Is this a connection to a sprayer?

Comment: @JimStewart - It connects to the faucet which has a pull-down spraying head.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the make of the faucet or any replacement parts, so the resolution was to simply replace the entire thing.

Answer (score 4):

This is a proprietary part and versions of it are common on "pull out head" faucets.  I've installed them from Delta and Moen, and from what I remember they are slightly different. I've never seen them sold as a replacement part from DIY retailers.

Your best bet is to figure out what brand the faucet is and call customer support for a replacement part.  Sometimes companies send out small parts for free because they know they break easily and are proprietary, but usually there's a small cost but much better than buying a whole new faucet!

Answer (score 1):

I've been handed major-brand replacement parts for free at a local big-box store. They said it was manufacturer policy. You do need to figure out which big-box chain carries the brand, as they each may have partnered with one of them.

Comment: I had an experience with a brand-new faucet/sprayer missing a part - end result after getting the manufacturer to send me a part, but it was the wrong one, was back to Big Orange and they opened up new faucets to find the right parts for me - fantastic service! But the real point is that within one very specific model of one major brand, there were *two* variants at the time with different combinations of sprayer parts (and then my box was missing one of those parts) - so you need to actually bring the broken parts, not just model #s, to get the right replacement.