# What is this plumbing fitting connected to the kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I'm looking to install a water filter under my kitchen sink for the cold water line, but I ran into a fitting I've never seen before. I can't find pictures of anything similar when searching online. The water filter's line won't connect with this fitting, so I'm searching for a specific adapter or converter.

What is the name of this type of hose end?

[image: mystery hose end]

And this type of quick connector that hose fits into?

[image: mystery connector]

Comment: I have only seen these for suppply to the fridge

Comment: This looks like some proprietary fitting. Can you give us more context? What's at the opposite ends of the two hoses pictured?

Comment: @GregHill The other end of the first hose is attached to the cold water valve. The opposite end of the hose with the quick connector goes to a pull-out style faucet head.

Comment: @Armand While that piece is different from mine, I do believe the top answer there still relates to my question! It is a pull-out style faucet head and you can make out "MOEN" on the connector in my second pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, in fact, a proprietary hose and quick connector made by MOEN. You can make out the brand name in the second photo from the question.

Here's the same connector construction in diverter form:

[image: MOEN quick-connect diverter]

Searching online for "MOEN pull out faucet hose" or "MOEN quick connector" will produce results for the same type of hoses and connectors.

Kudos to @GregHill for identifying it as proprietary and @Armand for finding [a similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/whats-the-name-for-this-piece-attached-to-the-kitchen-faucet-hose) where the top answer mentions MOEN pull-out faucets specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @GregHill suggests, those are proprietary fittings used by the faucet manufacturer to simplify user installation of the faucet (connecting faucet sprayer/spigot to output of faucet control). That fitting connection should be downstream of the faucet control; your filter should be installed upstream of the faucet's cold water supply connection, perhaps at the shutoff.